# Auto-switching DNS records to new image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

We are currently using a single compute engine on GCP, and we want to start experimenting with some of the HashCorp suite when making changes to it. The plan was to use Packer for creating new images and then start up these images and then switch the DNS over to the new machine once that is up.

We have no experience with Terraform (outside of reading books), so is there a way of auto-switching the DNS over in Google using Terraform?

I have found the [Terraform DNS Provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/dns/index.html) and [google_dns_managed_zone](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/dns_managed_zone.html), but I am not sure how or if the two relate. We are not in any way experts of GCP either, so we wouldn't know where to start in the console for doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`google_dns_record_set` docs example](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/dns_record_set.html#binding-a-dns-name-to-the-ephemeral-ip-of-a-new-instance-) gives a good example of how you can attach create an A record that points to the IP address of an instance:

```
resource "google_dns_record_set" "frontend" {
  name = "frontend.${google_dns_managed_zone.prod.dns_name}"
  type = "A"
  ttl  = 300

  managed_zone = "${google_dns_managed_zone.prod.name}"

  rrdatas = ["${google_compute_instance.frontend.network_interface.0.access_config.0.assigned_nat_ip}"]
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "frontend" {
  name         = "frontend"
  machine_type = "g1-small"
  zone         = "us-central1-b"

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-8"
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network       = "default"
    access_config = {}
  }
}

resource "google_dns_managed_zone" "prod" {
  name     = "prod-zone"
  dns_name = "prod.mydomain.com."
}
```

While this will handle creating an instance and attaching a record to it, it relies on a hard-coded image name (requiring you to make a change to your Terraform config when you create a new image with Packer) and Terraform's default lifecycle rules will mean that [when the image does change it will force a new instance to be created](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/blob/8ada4ffdb2b742580e9892d4347b2b3729dfd0a4/google/resource_compute_instance.go#L105-L111), destroying the old one first and then replacing it with a new instance.

Ideally you probably want to have Packer publish new images in a family and have Terraform automatically use the latest image in that family on the next apply with no configuration changes. If you want to avoid downtime you probably also want to force Terraform to create a new instance before flipping the DNS record over and then destroying the old instance.

Thankfully all this is pretty easy to do!

#### Using Packer and Terraform to automatically publish and pick up new images

Using the [Packer `googlecompute` builder](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/googlecompute.html) you can publish images as part of an [`image_family`](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/googlecompute.html#image_family):

```
{
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "googlecompute",
      "account_file": "account.json",
      "project_id": "my project",
      "source_image_family": "debian-cloud/debian-8",
      "image_family": "my-image-family",
      "ssh_username": "packer",
      "zone": "us-central1-a"
    }
  ],
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "ansible",
      "playbook_file": "./path/to/playbook.yml"
    }
  ]
}
```

We can then use Terraform's [`google_compute_image` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/d/datasource_compute_image.html) to find the most recent published image in an image family and make the [`google_compute_instance` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_instance.html) pick this up automatically on the next Terraform action (plan/apply etc):

```
data "google_compute_image" "my_image" {
  family = "my-image-family"
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "frontend" {
  # ...

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "${data.google_compute_image.my_image.self_link}"
    }
  }

  # ...
}
```

#### Creating the new instance before destroying the old one

Now that we have Terraform automatically picking up changes to our published images we also need to make sure that this doesn't cause us outages as Terraform replaces the instance.

To do this we simply change the default [lifecycle](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#lifecycle) model for the `google_compute_instance` resource by specifying:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "frontend" {
  # ...

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Terraform will then attempt to create the new instance before removing the old one so the dependency graph goes from:

```
destroy old instance -> create new instance -> change DNS record
```

to:

```
create new instance -> change DNS record -> destroy old instance
```

---

Note that all of the above is untested and coming from someone who doesn't use GCE but does do similar things with Packer and Terraform in AWS. If I've made a mistake in any of my assumptions about GCE or the code doesn't work exactly then edits are welcomed!

Comment: Fantastic answer! Will need to wait before I get to test it though:-)